# Replace \item with \MyItem to box each list member with an mdframed

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, mdframed

Since it was pointed out that redefining `\item` can be dangerous in [strange interaction between `mdframed` and `\item`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47397/strange-interaction-between-mdframed-and-item), I am wondering if there are going to be problems with this solution.

My goal is to replace:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
    \MyItem \TextA
    \MyItem \TextB
\end{enumerate}
```

[image]

with (i.e., only the environment name is changed):

```
\begin{MyEnumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
    \MyItem \TextA
    \MyItem \TextB
\end{MyEnumerate}
```

to obtain an `mdframe` around each item:

[image]

The solution as below seems to work, at least for this test case. So, is this way of using `\MyItem` instead of `\item` have hidden dangers that are not obvious in this test case.

### Notes:

- This seems a lot like [Box around a few items in an itemize environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/box-around-a-few-items-in-an-itemize-environment/), but is different in that I want this frame around each item, and do need to use `mdframed` as opposed to just a `tikz` rectangle.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% for toggles
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\TextA}{%
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
        Sed accumsan hendrerit velit, vitae ultrices sapien porta nec.  
}%
\newcommand{\TextB}{%
        Duis blandit tempus placerat. 
        Nulla vitae erat ante. Nulla facilisi. 
        Aliquam tristique interdum suscipit. 
        Duis posuere orci vel velit suscipit in porttitor purus eleifend. 
}%


\newcommand{\MyItem}{\item}

\newtoggle{FirstItem}%
\toggletrue{FirstItem}%
\newenvironment{MyEnumerate}[1][]{%
    \renewcommand{\MyItem}{%
        \iftoggle{FirstItem}{%
            \global\togglefalse{FirstItem}
            %--------- start new frame
            \begin{mdframed}[skipbelow=2pt]%
            \begin{enumerate}[#1,series=MySeries]%
        }{%
            \end{enumerate}%
            \end{mdframed}%
            %--------- end previous frame and start new one
            \begin{mdframed}[skipbelow=2pt]%
            \begin{enumerate}[#1,resume*=MySeries]%
        }%
        \item%
    }%
}{%
    \end{enumerate}%
    \end{mdframed}% --------- end last frame
    \global\toggletrue{FirstItem}%
}%

\begin{document}\noindent
\textbf{enumerate:}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
    \MyItem \TextA
    \MyItem \TextB
\end{enumerate}
%
\medskip
\textbf{MyEnumerate:}
\begin{MyEnumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
    \MyItem \TextA
    \MyItem \TextB
\end{MyEnumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it's easier to provide a command like `mydoubleline` which will be passed before every item is set.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: That seems like redefining `\item` which according to the linked question is dangerous. Or, perhaps I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: The command must be set by hand. You are right your solution is more comfortable.

Comment: I tested your example and it works well with the current version at github -- Great. (Side note: `mdframed` loads `etoolbox`)

Comment: I suggest to answer your own question with *works well* ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>this cw is to reduce the unanswered questions</sub>

In my opinion your code works well.