# Avoid pagebreak in enumerate

Tags: page-breaking, enumerate

I am writing a lot of survey reports in which I need to answer specific questions.
I stumbled upon `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}` and `\begin{enumerate}[a)]`, respectively, which does exactly what I want.

However, at the moment, I need to input pagebreaks by hand if the question and the corresponding answer gets to the next page and was wondering if this could be corrected "automatically". Let me explain this with the help of some code and a picture.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[a)] % a), b), c), ...

\item \textbf{Lorem ipsum 1?}

\lipsum
...

\item \textbf{Lorem ipsum xxx?}

\lipsum

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

As you can see in the attached image, the item does not use a new page even if it does not fit as a whole on the actual page. How can this be changed?

---

#### Picture:

[image: Enumerate pagebreaks]

Comment: I assume you want the item to have started on the next page?  (PS The lipsum package can produce the standard lorem ipsum text without you needing to type/paste it all in, making for a much shorter example.)

Comment: @Teepeemm: Updated the question.

Comment: maybe this will help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/76483/page-breaks-within-enumerated-list