# Vertical line & list environment

Tags: lists, page-breaking

I would like to make a good looking environment for my proofs. Some are spread on two pages so i thought of the list environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{list}{\underline{Proof} :}{\leftmargin=0.6cm \setlength{\labelwidth}{10pt}}
\item \lipsum
\end{list}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

What i want is a vertical line starting approximatively under the 'r' of proof and that continue on the second page.

In fact It is quite similar to this question [Vertical line enclosing items in itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45742/vertical-line-enclosing-items-in-itemize) wich unfortunately didn't find no answer.

Comment: You may want to use the `mdframed` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to turn it into an environment; for large first lines one can do some manual adjustment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newenvironment{Proof}[1][1.9ex]
  {\par\bigskip\vspace{#1}
   \begin{mdframed}[outerlinewidth=2,leftmargin=10,%
     rightmargin=-10pt,backgroundcolor=white,hidealllines=true,leftline=true,%
     innertopmargin=0pt,splittopskip=\topskip,skipbelow=\baselineskip,innerbottommargin=0pt%
     skipabove=\baselineskip]%
     \vspace{-#1}\hspace{-12.2mm}\underline{Proof} : \ignorespaces}
  {\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{Proof}
\lipsum
\end{Proof}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{Proof}[2.1ex]
abc$\sum$\lipsum
\end{Proof}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the optional argument you put the necessary adjustment if the first line has descenders or ascenders that go beyond the underlined "Proof".

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to egreg for the indication. After some trys i got what i wanted, that is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\Proof}[1]{%
\bigskip\bigskip
\begin{mdframed}[outerlinewidth=2,leftmargin=10,%
rightmargin=-10pt,backgroundcolor=white,hidealllines=true,leftline=true,%
innertopmargin=0pt,splittopskip=\topskip,skipbelow=\baselineskip,innerbottommargin=0pt%
skipabove=\baselineskip]%
\vspace{-3mm}\hspace{-12.2mm}\underline{Proof} : #1
\end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1] \Proof\lipsum \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately it won't work if the first line height is bigger than usual ..